# Google appengine authentication restrict to domain not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-authentication

I'm trying to restrict access for a google appengine website to accounts of a specific Google Apps-Domain. In the Google Developers Console in app settings, I've already set the authentication method to "Google Apps-Domain" and entered the domain in the format "xxx.com". But when I'm testing this on my local webserver test page that I've set up, Google still lets me sign in with accounts that are not managed by the domain that I configured. Did I miss something? How can I restrict access to accounts of that domain without "manually" (aka doing it on my server) checking for the domain-string in the e-mail address of the user that just logged in to my appengine site?

Comment: You said in your local development server all accounts pass, but what happens in the GAE servers? did you try that?

Comment: I did not try that because it is not yet deployed to the GAE servers. I don't want to deploy prior to it working locally. I hope it is still possible.

EDIT: Also as far as I understand it, there should be no difference in behaviour since the user is redirected to the Google log-in for authentication anyway.

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn't but definitely it should work with the deployment servers and deploying some simple code would allow you to check if that works or not. There are too many moving parts involved to not discard the development server is the issue first

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the development server knows nothing about what you've configured in the console and has a [simple mock login](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_Google_accounts_and_the_development_server) that allows you to test whether (i) the user is logged in and (ii) the user is an admin.

Comment: @tx802 I'm not getting to a mock login page, if I click the sign-in button I'm redirected to the normal google sign in. If I log in then I can obtain data from the logged in user, all of that is ok. But I want the Google Sign-In to check whether a user of a certain Google App-domain is accessing the site.

Comment: @ZigMandel As mentioned there shouldn't be a difference since I'm getting the standard Google Sign-In page when trying to sign-in to my site. It is just not restricting access to users of a certain Google-Apps domain as configured.

Comment: As mentioned already, try on a real deploy. What you ask DOES happen on a real deploy.

Comment: @Mario Ok I've tested it on the GAE servers now, the result stays the same though. I can successfully login with accounts from different domains not matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from the [GAE official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Using_Users):

> Using Users
>
> The development web server simulates Google Accounts with its own
>   sign-in and sign-out pages. While running under the development web
>   server, the methods that generate sign-in and sign-out URLs return
>   URLs for /_ah/login and /_ah/logout on the local server.
>
> The development sign-in page includes a form where you can enter an
>   email address. Your session uses whatever email address you enter as
>   the active user.
>
> To have the application believe that the logged-in user is an
>   administrator, check the "Sign in as Administrator" checkbox on the
>   form.

In other words, if you see the real Google login form is because you're doing something else than using the plain development server, which, by the way, doesn't have a clue about your settings in the Developers' Console.

Comment: I'm going to check it again.

Comment: "The development sign-in page includes a form where you can enter an email address. Your session uses whatever email address you enter as the active user." That doesn't work. So it seems to be the real Google login page. Although I don't see why it gives me that site, since I've deployed a development (.appspot) domain via the gcloud command of the Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: "In other words, if you see the real Google login form is because you're doing something else than using the plain development server, which, by the way, doesn't have a clue about your settings in the Developers' Console." I'm not convinced about that. Since if I'm passing the wrong Client-ID to the content attribute of the google-signin-client_id meta tag in my index.php and try to sign in, then I'm getting an error which doesn't happen if I'm passing the right one. So the login form I'm getting by Google MUST know about my settings in the Developers' Console. Else that wouldn't happen.

Comment: Deploying to an appspot.com domain is not your development server. Development server is the server you run locally and access your local mock services. The appspot.com is a production service which you can redirect by using custom domains, which is what you want to do at the end. This is the login page you should see when using the Java development server https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Then I conclude that what I'd like to do is not possible and I have to check the user credentials on my backend.
EDIT: Also I'm going to accept your answer, since your comments at least pointed me to the conclusion.

Comment: What you wanted is to allow only users from a given custom domain that is registered under Google Apps? If it's that you should be able to do it, not in the local development server but definitely in the the production one. If it's that, let me know to help you further.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to achieve. But how can I be sure that it works, if I cannot test that in a development environment but only in a production environment?

Comment: You could try the Guestbook example deployed to your production (appspot.com) server and try to access it with accounts from your allowed domain and others (like gmail.com) and see if you it works or not, and once you have it working, it should work the same with your own app.

Comment: Is there an example version for PHP?

Comment: Yes, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld although it's called Hello World it's the guestbook for PHP version